# Pygame Keyup/Keydown

Tags: python, pygame, keydown, keyup

I'm making a little Mario for my school's Computer Club. (well, as part of a team.) 
Anyway, I'm having some trouble with the "keyup/keydown" commands. Here's my code:

```
# 1 - Import library
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# 2 - Initialize the game
pygame.init()
width, height = 1280, 1000
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
keys = [False, False, False, False]
playerpos=[100,100]

# 3 - Load images
player = pygame.image.load("images/totallynotgodzilla.png")
# 3.1 - Load Audio
music = pygame.mixer.Sound("audio/skyrim.wav")

# 4 - keep looping through
while 1:
    # 5 - clear the screen before drawing it again
    screen.fill(0)
    # 6 - draw the screen elements
    screen.blit(player, playerpos)
    # 7 - update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    # 8 - loop through the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_w:
                keys[0]=True
            elif event.key==K_a:
                keys[1]=True
            elif event.key==K_s:
                keys[2]=True
            elif event.key==K_d:
                keys[3]=True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_w:
                keys[0]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_a:
                keys[1]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_s:
                keys[2]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_d:
                keys[3]=False

        # 9 - Move player
        if keys[0]:
            playerpos[1]-=5
        elif keys[2]:
            playerpos[1]+=5
        if keys[1]:
            playerpos[0]-=5
        elif keys[3]:
            playerpos[0]+=5
```

Basically, the problem is that when I press a key down, it waits for the keyup command to happen before moving again. So basically I have to rapidly press down the buttons to move.

I deleted some of the code, so if something is missing, let me know and I'll tell you whether or not I have it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indenting problem. You need to test your key states in you main game loop not in your event loop. You need to UNINDENT your keystate test one level.

```
while 1:
    # do init stuff 
    screen.fill(0)
    # .... (all main loop init stuff here)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # test events, set key states
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_w:
                keys[0]=True
        # .... (all event stuff)

    # Indent moves back to main game loop
    # test key states here...
    if keys[0]:
        playerpos[1]-=5
    elif keys[2]:
        playerpos[1]+=5
    # .... (and so on)
```