# How do I make it so it goes to a new scene on keypress? (Pygame)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, scene

I am very new and I cant seem to find any tutorials on how to do this.  I would imagine it would be pretty simple. I am creating an Oregon Trail type game and I need it to go to the next picture when you press E, or quit the program when you press Q.

Here is my code:

```
# 1 - Import library
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# 2 - Initialize the game
pygame.init()
width, height = 1000, 800
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# 3 - Load images
background = pygame.image.load("start.png")

# 4 - keep looping through
while 1:
    # 5 - clear the screen before drawing it again
    screen.fill(0)
    # 6 - draw the screen elements
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    # 7 - update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    # 8 - loop through the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check if the event is the X button 
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            # if it is quit the game
            pygame.quit() 
            exit(0)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811132 << Pygame key events

Comment: Okay so that seems pretty easy but I have no idea how to make it change scenes

Comment: Are you sure a textured UI isn't better than something like Pygame for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
# 1 - Import library
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# 2 - Initialize the game
pygame.init()
width, height = 1000, 800
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# 3 - Load images
background = pygame.image.load("start.png")

# 4 - keep looping through
while 1:
    # 5 - clear the screen before drawing it again
    screen.fill(0)
    # 6 - draw the screen elements
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    # 7 - update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    # 8 - loop through the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                background = pygame.image.load("stage2.png")
        # check if the event is the X button 
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            # if it is quit the game
            pygame.quit() 
            exit(0)
```

Of course this will only work for 2 images of background "start.png" and stage2.png". But you can create a list and cicle through it.

Comment: Actually, a generator function my be more suited to this. He could have a function that yields an item from a list every time it's called with `next()`.

Comment: Works! Would you know how I could make it so that you have to have a certain image to be the background for the keypress to work?

Comment: @Nick add an if statement before assigning the background variable. As I told you, the simplest way to keep track of your current background would be to set it in a list, then keep a variable with the current index of the backgrounds you are displaying, and so, the condition of your if can be based on that index. This is a very simple aproach. Good luck.

Comment: @kstenger Ok if you or anyone could help me with one more thing that would be great! I can't seem to get the if statement correct:
if event.key == pygame.K_e:
       if image == ("start.png"):
              background = pygame.image.load("blahblah.png")

Comment: @Nick edit your original question an add the code you are trying now